# XHR Unable to Load with Django Project

Tags: javascript, html, django, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I'm in traineeship in a company and I need to used the program of another trainee who programmed it in 2012. So I have done some update but I have a some problems :

When I press a button, I have a JS that make a `xhr.get` to recover a `JSON`. But I have this message on my firefox console :

```
Object { message: "Unable to load /query/?typeForm=com…", stack:".cache["dojo/errors/create"]/</</g@…", response: Object, status: 0,responseText: "", xhr: XMLHttpRequest }
```

My JS :

```
function queryDataGrid(map, stringForm) {
var test = "pouet";
require(["dojox/grid/DataGrid",
         "dojo/store/Memory",
         "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
         "dojo/_base/xhr",
         "dojo/domReady!",
         "dojo/dom",
         "dojo/_base/array"],
function(DataGrid, Memory, ObjectStore, xhr, arrayUtil, dom) {
    var nodeDomGrid = dom.byId("datagrid");
    window.alert("hey");
    xhr.get({
        url: "/query/",
        form: dom.byId(stringForm),
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(data) {
            var nodeDomGrid = dom.byId("datagrid");
            var nodeGrid = dijit.byId("datagrid");

            var gridLayout = [];
            var dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore:new Memory({ data: data.fields }) });
            console.log("store");
            console.log(data.fields[0][1]);

            globalData = data;

            for(i in data.columns) {
                gridLayout.push({
                    name: data.columns[i],
                    field: data.columns[i],
                    width: "auto"
                })
            }

            nodeGrid.setStructure(gridLayout);
            nodeGrid.setStore(dataStore);

            var nodeMap = dom.byId("map");

            columns = data.columns;
            columnsToDisplay = []

            numberColumn = 0;
            for (i in columns) {
                if (columns[i] == "Distance Fin") {
                    numberColumn = i
                }
                if (parseInt(i) > parseInt(numberColumn) && numberColumn != 0) {
                    columnsToDisplay.push({ value: columns[i], label: columns[i]});
                }
            }
            dijit.byId("dataToColor").addOption(columnsToDisplay);

            var vectorLayer = map.getLayersByName("KML")[0];
            vectorLayer.removeAllFeatures();
            var kmlFile = createKMLFile(data.kmldata, dom.byId("hiddenColor").value, dom.byId("sizeLine").value, dom.byId("colourPR").style.backgroundColor, dom.byId("sizePR").value);
            var features = KMLToFeatures(kmlFile);
            var bounds;
            for(var i=0; i<features.length; ++i) {
                if (!bounds) {
                    bounds = features[i].geometry.getBounds();
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(features[i].geometry.getBounds());
                }

            }
            vectorLayer.addFeatures(features);
            console.log(vectorLayer);

            map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
            refreshLayer(vectorLayer);

            if (stringForm == "commonQueriesForm" && dijit.byId("table").get("value") == "location") {
                dom.byId("colourPalette").style.display = "block";
                dom.byId("styleKML").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                dom.byId("colourPalette").style.display = "none";
                dom.byId("styleKML").style.display = "block";
            }
        },
        // Message d'erreur à modifier
        error: function() {
            nodeDomGrid.innerHTML = "La requête a engendré une erreur.";
        }
    })
});

console.log(stringForm);
};
```

My Form :

```
<form id="commonQueriesForm" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" onload="alert('test')">
<p>
<div id="commonDataTitlePane" data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Requêtes'">
    <input type="text" name="typeForm" id="typeForm" value="common" style="display:none" />
    <select name="table" id="table" class="cSelect" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
    data-dojo-props="onChange:function(){ if (dijit.byId('table').get('value') == 'location') {dijit.byId('age').set('disabled', true); } else {dijit.byId('age').set('disabled', false); }}"> 
        {% for key, value in dictTablesDatabase.items %}
            <option value="{{ key }}">{{ key }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
            <option value="location">Repérages</option>
        </select><br />
        <select name="road" id="road" class="cSelect" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" data-dojo-props="">
            <option value="all">Toutes les routes</option>
                {% for road in listRoad %}
            <option value="{{ road|first|cut:' ' }}">{{ road|first|cut:' ' }}</option> 
                {% endfor %}
        </select><br />
        <select name="age" id="age" class="cSelect" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" data-dojo-props="">
            {% for age in arrayNumber %}
                <option value="{{ age }}">{{ age }}</option> 
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
</div>
<button type="executeButton" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" onClick="queryDataGrid(map, 'commonQueriesForm');">Lancer la requête</button>
</p>
</form>
```

urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from GSRBaseWeb.Home import views as myapp_views

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'GSRBaseWeb.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^GSRBaseWeb/', include('GSRBaseWeb.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^home/$',myapp_views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^home/query', myapp_views.queryDataGrid, name='queryDataGrid'),

]
```

views.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from GSRBaseWeb.Utils.utils import Utils
from GSRBaseWeb.DataAccess.databaseAccess import DatabaseAccess
from GSRBaseWeb.DataAccess.GSRBaseDLLAccess import GSRBaseDLLAccess
from ctypes import *

# Envoie les données nécessaires aux différents formulaires
def home(request):
    dictToSend = {}

    data = DatabaseAccess()
    dictTablesDatabase = data.dataToDisplay()
    dictToSend["dictTablesDatabase"] = dictTablesDatabase

    # Sélection de l'ensemble des routes
    queryRoads = "SELECT id_route, nom FROM routes"
    listRoad = data.executeQuery(queryRoads)
    dictToSend["listRoad"] = listRoad

    # Liste pour les âges
    arrayNumber = []
    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        arrayNumber.append(i)
        i += 1
    arrayNumber.append("Tous")
    dictToSend["arrayNumber"] = arrayNumber

    # Liste pour les emplacements
    arrayLocation = ["Tous", " ", "D", "C", "G"]
    dictToSend["arrayLocation"] = arrayLocation

    return render(request, 'Home/home.html', context=dictToSend)

# Récupère le contenu d'un formulaire et le traite en fonction du type de formulaire (commun, simple ou complexe)
def queryDataGrid(request):
    # request.GET renvoie un QueryDict (objet Django)
    print("YOLO")
    parametersContent = request.GET
    whatForm = parametersContent.getlist("typeForm")[0]
    print(type(whatForm))
    try:
        accessDLL = GSRBaseDLLAccess()
    except:
       print(Exception.message())
    if whatForm == "common":

        table = parametersContent.getlist("table")[0]
        road = parametersContent.getlist("road")[0]
        if table != "location":
            if parametersContent.getlist("age")[0] == "Tous":
                age = 20
                print("True")
            else:
                print("False")
                age = int(unicode(parametersContent.getlist("age")[0]))
        if road == "all":
            road = ""

        # on fait une requête sur les repérages
        if table == "location":
            result, number = accessDLL.requete_reperage(road)
        else:
            result, number = accessDLL.requete_table(table, road, age)

    elif whatForm == "simple":
        """
        On fait le traitement du formulaire de requêtes simples
        Prendre en compte des ajouts des formulaires
        On va prendre en compte les différentes lignes du formulaire et leur nombre """

        listConditions = []

        # Lignes des données
        listQueries = dataProcessingForm("Simple", parametersContent)

        # Checkout et les routes
        conditionCheckout = parametersContent.getlist("conditionCheckout")[0]
        conditionRoad = parametersContent.getlist("conditionRoad")[0]
        conditionRoad = 'ROUTE()="' + conditionRoad + '"'
        listConditions.append(conditionRoad)

        # Lignes des conditions
        j = 1
        while j < 6:
            if parametersContent.__contains__("conditionData" + str(j)) == True:
                data = parametersContent.getlist("conditionData" + str(j))[0]
                # On récupère la table de la condition
                table = data.split(":")[0]
                location = parametersContent.getlist("conditionLocation" + str(j))[0]
                age = parametersContent.getlist("conditionAge" + str(j))[0]
                condition = parametersContent.getlist("condition" + str(j))[0]
                value = parametersContent.getlist("valueCondition" + str(j))[0]
                conditionLine = "(" + data + condition
                if (str(value).isdigit()):
                    conditionLine += str(value)
                else:
                    conditionLine += '"' + str(value) + '"'
                conditionLine += ' ET ' + table + ':generation=' + str(age) + ' ET ' + table + ':emplacement="' + location + '")'
                if conditionCheckout == "anything":
                    conditionLine += "NON" + conditionLine
                listConditions.append(conditionLine)
            else:
                break;
            j += 1
        #@todo modifier la condition pour la Route(), ajouter un ET tout le temps
        if conditionCheckout == "atLeast":
            conditionQuery = ' OR '.join(listConditions)
        elif conditionCheckout == "all":
            conditionQuery = ' ET '.join(listConditions)

        result, number = accessDLL.requete_avancee(listQueries, conditionQuery)

    elif whatForm == "complex":
        # On fait le traitement du formulaire de requêtes complexes

        listQueries = dataProcessingForm("Complex", parametersContent)
        conditionQuery = parametersContent.getlist("textareaConditions")[0]
        result, number = accessDLL.requete_avancee(listQueries, conditionQuery)

    json = ""
    if number[0] > 0:
        # json à renvoyer en fonction des données des formulaires
        listResult = []
        i = 0
        while i <= number[0]:
            listResult.append(result[i])
            i += 1
        json = Utils.jsonSerializeQueryResult(listResult)
        print(json)

    return HttpResponse(content=json,
                        status=200,
                        mimetype="text/plain")

def dataProcessingForm(form, parametersContent):
    """ Mise en forme des données des formulaires pour les requêtes
    La mise en forme est faite pour la DLL utilisée qui effectue le plus gros des requêtes
    """    
    listQueries = []
    i = 1
    while i < 6:
        if parametersContent.__contains__("data" + form + str(i)) == True:
            data = parametersContent.getlist("data" + form + str(i))[0]
            location = parametersContent.getlist("location" + form + str(i))[0]
            if parametersContent.getlist("age" + form + str(i))[0] == "Tous":
                age = 20
            else:
                age = int(unicode(parametersContent.getlist("age" + form + str(i))[0]))
            contentToAdd = data + "," + location + "," + str(age)
            print(contentToAdd)
            listQueries.append(contentToAdd)
        else:
            break;
        i += 1

    return ";".join(listQueries)
```

Comment: Indicating in the title that's a Django project will be more likely to get you an attention to cause a possible answer.

Comment: You should expand a message from that JSON you have provided first.
e.g. Unable to load /query/?typeForm=com…

Comment: Precisely, I don't know how to display what is hidden.

Answer (score -1):

The JS code is trying to load the absolute path `/query/`, but your Django patterns are setup to respond to `^home/query`. Try using `/home/query` as your xhr URL.

Comment: -1; the question here is clearly in violation of the *"Questions seeking debugging help ... must include ... the shortest code necessary"* and should be closed, not answered.

Comment: Knowing how much code is strictly necessary may not be clear to someone describing themselves as a "trainee". Even if it were, I don't think down voting an answer is particularly helpful.

Comment: *'Knowing how much code is strictly necessary may not be clear to someone describing themselves as a "trainee"'* -
 entirely their problem. If they can't create a contribution of value, they shouldn't post here. *"Even if it were, I don't think down voting an answer is particularly helpful"* - I understand that perspective and am sure many share it, but I personally disagree; I want to discourage you from answering questions like this one because I believe they harm the site and that answering them encourages them to be posted. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194989/200582.

Comment: While I appreciate the goal of encouraging high quality questions and answers, down voting a legitimate answer to a topical, if arguably ill-framed, question isn't really helping anyone. A more useful response would be to provide a bit of friendly advice to the original poster about how to properly frame questions. If the question really has no value, down vote it, too. Just keep in mind that voting is a quality filter, not a punishment/reward system (unless you're really invested in SO as a game).